# How to prefix every line of the output of a child_process spawn() call with text?

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, stdout, child-process

I execute several processes using `spawn()` from `child_process`.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

spawn("sh", ["script1.sh"], { shell: false, stdio: "inherit"});
spawn("sh", ["script2.sh"], { shell: false, stdio: "inherit"});
spawn("sh", ["script3.sh"], { shell: false, stdio: "inherit"});
```

**Question:** How to prefix the output of the scripts with text?

The idea is that I would be able to easily distinguish what each script logs.

I went through the `spawn` documentation but couldn't find anything that would help achieve this.

Note: I cannot modify the scripts.

Answer (score 8):

You have `stdio` set to `"inherit"`.

If you set this to `"pipe"`, Node.js will give you back [readable streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams) for `stderr` and `stdin`, which you can use to add your prefix.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const one = spawn("sh", ["script1.sh"], { shell: false, stdio: "pipe"});
let oneStdout = ''
one.stdout.on('data', function (chunk) {
  oneStdout += chunk
  const lines = oneStdout.split('\n')
  while(lines.length > 1) {
    const line = lines.shift()
    console.log('one',line)
  }
  oneStdout = lines.shift()
})
one.stdout.on('end', function () {
  console.log('one', oneStdout)
})
```

Here is the relevant section in the docs: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_stdio

Potential gotcha:

When "prefixing" you likely want to prefix each *new line* but not all scripts write to stdout a full line at a time. Play around with a few scripts that use `echo -n "foobar"` throughout the output to test that you're handling line breaks correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I run external commands and capture their output, e.g. to prefix each line with a timestamp:

```js
const { spawn } = require("child_process"),
  command = "echo",
  args = ["Studies have shown that people watch TV more than any other appliance."];

const child = spawn(command, args);

child.stdout.on('data', buff => {
  const line = buff.toLocaleString();
  console.info(new Date(), line);
});
child.stderr.on('data', buff => { // also catch any error output
  const line = buff.toLocaleString();
  console.error(new Date(), line);
});
child.on('exit', code => {console.info(`Command exited with code ${code}`)});
```

Here's what it looks like when you run it:

```sh
$ node thatScript.js 
2020-12-10T11:46:51.455Z Studies have shown that people watch TV more than any other appliance.

Command exited with code 0
$
```